# Subset Numpy Array where Values within Specified Range

Tags: numpy

Given the following array how do I return a new array containing the first value of each group of values within a specified range. There may be anything upwards of 2 such values.

Eg

```
specified_range = 10

in_array = np.array([3, 14, 25, 37, 38, 50, 61, 66, 70])
```

Groups of values within specified_range: [37, 38] and [61, 66, 70]

Desired result: [37 61]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the array is sorted in an ascending order, Use the following code:

```
s = np.diff(in_array) < specified_range
in_array[:-1][s & (np.r_[False, s[:-1]] != s)]

array([37, 61])
```

Comment: Great answer @Onyambu. If I wanted to change the threshold for the number of values from 2 to, eg, 3 how would I do that?

Comment: @Robsmith what do you mean? There is only one threshold, 10. I do not understand what 2 you are talking about. Just change the `specified_range = 3` and use the code

Comment: I mean instead of looking for 2 or more values within the specified_range coudl I adjust it to look for 3 or more values in the specified_range? Thanks

Comment: @Robsmith that will be a different question altogether. So far, this looks for any number of points within the range. In the case you want atleast n number of points, you could use `rle` to determine group size and only select groups with meet the specified criteria

Comment: @Robsmith use `np.diff(np.where(np.r_[False, s[:-1]] != s)[0])+1` to determine the group sizes, select the groups with the sizes that you want